# read from Ultrasonic HC-SR04

Tags: microcontroller, programming-languages, ultrasonic-sensors

i want to run two HC-SR04 on one PIC16F877A and send the value mesured by the two ultrasonic to serial port.

this is my code using PIC C Compiler :

```
#use rs232(baud=9600,parity=N,xmit=PIN_C6,rcv=PIN_C7,bits=8) 
#define e1 PIN_B6
#define t1 pin_B7 
#define e2 pin_B4 
#define t2 pin_B5 
int a; 
int distanse(int,int); 

void main()
{

while(1){
int u1,u2;
u1=distanse(e1,t1);u2=distanse(e2,t2);
printf("%3u", u1);
printf("%3u", u2);
delay_ms(1000);

}
}

int distanse(int e,int t){
long long counter=0;
output_bit(t,1);delay_us(10);output_bit(t,0);
a=input(e);
while(a==0){a=input(e);}
while(a==1){counter=counter+1;a=input(e);}
return counter/3.333333;
}
```

but the computer received random values ! 
what is the problem ?

Comment: For debugging, add a printf of counter in your so-called "distanse" function.  Maybe the long long counter result isn't fitting into an integer

Answer (score 1):

Ultrasonic sensors work by emitting a set of pulses and reading the return signal ([here](https://www.teachengineering.org/view_lesson.php?url=collection/umo_/lessons/umo_sensorswork/umo_sensorswork_lesson06.xml) is a better overview), this causes problems when you have more than one as they cannot distinguish between their own sensor and the other. I would suggest putting a 500ms delay after each reading to avoid as much interference as possible while you keep the same read rate.